# Read a string of coordinates in R and convert it into shape

Tags: r, coordinates

I'm working in R with a big csv with coordinates but I don't know how to deal with the format of the given coordinates.

Here's an example of one of my strings:

```
MULTIPOLYGON (((-642056.566199999 4428530.5303, -642062.897 4428529.6364, -642079.686700001 4428531.6674, -642130.2502 4428544.4759, -642161.394900002 4428551.1292, -642189.1721 4428557.0405, -642210.7051 4428564.1239, -642262.202799998 4428570.2739, -642260.751600001 4428582.7468, -642258.624200001 4428601.0329, -642255.114 4428631.2047, -642252.380899999 4428654.6952, -642249.209199999 4428681.9574, -642247.635699999 4428695.4821, -642245.851399999 4428710.8186, -642241.074200001 4428713.2175, -642234.840999998 4428716.3476, -642227.924899999 4428719.8211, -642185.8728 4428740.941, -642174.927999999 4428741.3978, -642161.524500001 4428741.952, -642155.883400001 4428742.1793, -642155.845899999 4428742.1804, -642114.091400001 4428752.6465, -642104.569800001 4428755.0334, -642090.8693 4428758.4683, -642023.184999999 4428769.2764, -641998.456700001 4428773.2294, -641973.522799999 4428777.2155, -641981.400400002 4428739.3047, -641998.386399999 4428666.0525, -642027.050299998 4428559.89, -642031.101100002 4428542.6747, -642030.149999999 4428542.5609, -642030.691300001 4428542.1653, -642046.154100001 4428536.8245, -642055.270300001 4428531.9096, -642056.566199999 4428530.5303)))
```

I found the following problem working with a GIS. Some features represented in pink, for some reason, show this error:
[image]

I've checked the coordinates and everything seems to be correct, that's why I'm trying to represent the geometries in R to see whether this is a problem of the GIS itself or not.

I have zero experience dealing with strings and formats in R.
The CRS of this multipolygon is SRID 3857  (PSEUDO-MERCATOR).

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you paste the output of `dput` on the above data that you provided?

Comment: Thank you very much @LC-datascientist , I tried that and it worked, unfortunatelly it didn't solve my problem... the geometries still show the same error, so my hypothesis was incorrect. I'm trying now to represent my polygons in R and discard whether is a problem with the GIS or not